# How to add multiple path in kubernetes-nginx-ingress-server-snippet-annotation to deny the traffic

Tags: kubernetes-ingress

I've the following code in the my ingress config, I would like to add more path(s) to deny the hits from Hackers. Is there any best practices to be followed to ensure no automated scans made by hackers?

```
---
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example
  labels:
    app: example
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "0"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "200"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      location ~* "^/boaform" {
          deny all;
          return 403;
        }
      location ~* "^/api" {
          deny all;
          return 403;
        }
      location ~* "^/user" {
          deny all;
          return 403;
        }
  namespace: example-ns
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than block some common URLs from hackers, you could do your best so they cannot even start the request. Good IP restrictions should be better to security than some blocked paths.

If you really need to listen to the world, then you could do yourself several kinds of implementations (request rate, geoIP, search for injections, etc) according to your application needs.

If you want no trouble (or less trouble) with these rules, you could try a WAF, like Cloudflare

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).